# Why is a non-convergent series simplified to zero?

Tags: symbolic, simplifying-expressions

```
Sum[Sin[n*x]*Sin[n] /. x -> 1, {n, 1, Infinity}] == 
  Sum[Sin[n*x]*Sin[n], {n, 1, Infinity}] /. x -> 1
```

> Sum::div: Sum does not converge. >>
>
> Sum::div: Sum does not converge. >>
>
> Sum[Sin[n]^2, {n, 1, Infinity}] == 0

Can anyone explain this?  I do not understand why `Sum[Sin[n*x]*Sin[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]` is automatically simplified to 0 when the series does not converge (unless `Mod[x, Pi] == 0` in which case the sum really is zero).

Comment: although this sum is wrong the partial sum given by Mathematica are correct. I have tested this sum with wolfram alpha and it gave me that it diverges so I assume that at v9 they have corrected it ...

Comment: No, same response from v9.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is you hit a distribution.

```
partialSum = Sum[Sin[n*x]*Sin[n], {n, 1, bigN}];
(*  1/4 Csc[(1 + x)/2] Sin[1/2 (-1 - 2 bigN - x - 2 bigN x)] 
   -1/4 Csc[(1 - x)/2] Sin[1/2 (-1 - 2 bigN + x + 2 bigN x)] *)
```

and you can immediately see from [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/) (7th from the top) that in the limit `bigN->Infinity` you get the sum of two Dirac functions centered at `-1` and `+1`.

So we can conclude that

```
Sum[Sin[n*x]*Sin[n], {n, 1, Infinity}] = -Pi/2 DiracDelta[x+1] + Pi/2 DiracDelta[x-1]
```

Another way to check this (not a full proof) is to make the sum convergent :

```
convSum =  Sum[Sin[n*x]*Sin[n] Exp[-eps n], {n, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions :> {eps > 0}];

result = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[convSum, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]
(* (Sin[1] Sin[x] Sinh[eps])/
   (1 + Cos[2] + Cos[2 x] - 4 Cos[1] Cos[x] Cosh[eps] + Cosh[2 eps]) *)

Plot3D[result, {x, -2, 2}, {eps, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

```
Limit[result, eps -> 0]
(* 0 *)
```

but :

```
Limit[result /. x -> -1, eps -> 0]
(* -Infinity *)

Limit[result /. x -> 1, eps -> 0]
(* Infinity *)
```